# ServiceStack: Handle query params in the form of "/people?includes=A,B,C

Tags: servicestack

Assuming an incoming GET request with the raw URL:

```
/people?includes=family,friends,enemies
```

From the service side, is adding a string[] property called "Includes" to my Request object, and parsing each item in the array, and then performing my business logic the right way to go?

Or perhaps, rather than going a string[] route, is there any way to strongly type this (maybe in a Flags enum?) so my clients and service can make this look nicer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [ServiceStack.Text.EnumMemberSerializer](https://github.com/Chatham/ServiceStack.Text.EnumMemberSerializer)

```
public enum ReturnPolicy
{
    NotSet = 0,
    [EnumMember(Value = @"90 Days w/Receipt")]
    _90DayswReceipt = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = @"15% Restocking Fee")]
    _15RestockingFee = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value = @"Exchange Only")]
    ExchangeOnly = 3,
    [EnumMember(Value = @"As-Is")]
    AsIs = 4,
    ...
}

public class ProductInfo
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public ReturnPolicy ReturnPolicy { get; set; }
    ...
}

http://myhost/products?returnpolicy=90%20Days%20w%2FReceipt
http://myhost/products?returnpolicy=90%20DaYS%20w%2FReceIPt
http://myhost/products?returnpolicy=_90DayswReceipt
http://myhost/products?returnpolicy=1
```